# How to allow rendering view only if accessed via iframe from specific domain in Django?

Tags: django, security, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a Django view which I want to be accessible only from an iframe inside a webpage inside domain.com. I don't want it to be accessible directly nor from any other domain.

Here are a list of use cases:

1. If user tries to access view directly in my website, a Forbidden error is thrown.
2. If user goes to www.domain.com and the webpage contains an iframe pointing to my view, the content of the view is displayed.
3. If user tries to copy same iframe code and paste it on another webpage from a different server, even if the server is pretending to be www.domain.com, he gets a forbidden error.
4. Any other hacky way to access the content outside from the real www.domain.com gets forbidden error.

Is it possible to do this? How can it be done?

I know of the `X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/` header, but first, this doesn't block direct access, second is it hacker safe?

Comment: Hi. I need the same functionality. Have you solved your problem?